# understanding the manual for google cast companion library

Tags: java, android, chromecast, google-cast

[SOLVED] I did not have the same namespace on both ends.

I have this [manual page](https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android/blob/master/CastCompanionLibrary.pdf) about the [Google cast companion library](https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android) and I don't understand the part about 'Support for data-centric applications' where it says

"This will send a message. Messages that are sent to the sender from the receiver can be
captured by extending DataCastConsumerImpl class and overriding the following callbacks:"

I have all the code for sending the message but when I press the 'confirmButton' nothing happens and the log doesn't throw any exceptions. So I wanted to add the 'onMessageSendFailed' callback but I have no idea how to add it to my code.

Thank you in advance for your help!
If you need more info I will be glad to give it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, what do you expect to happen when you send that message? Is your receiver registered to receive messages on that namespace? Is that not happening? You need to be more clear when you say "nothing happens". As for capturing `onMessageSendFailed()` callback, you need to either implement `IDataCastConsumer` or extend `DataCastConsumerImpl` and override the method(s) that you are interested in and then register your implementation with the `DataCastManager` instance:

```
mDataCastConsumerImpl = new DataCastConsumerImpl(){
   public void onMessageSendFailed(Status status) {
       // do as you want
   }
   ....
}

...
mDataCastManager.addDataCastConsumer(mDataCastConsumerImpl);
...
```

Comment: When i say "nothing happens" is that there is no log on the chromecast side of the message reaching it and tehre is no log of the message being sent on the android side. I wanted to add the message failed callback to get more info on sending the message.

Thanks for the answer ill set-up the callbacks now and update this post later.

Comment: Ok so I implemented the code like this in the OnCreate part.

Comment: and there is still no output in the log. I added "log.d(TAG, "sendmessage error")" to the override to see it in the log but there is nothing. I only get the log from my sendMessage call "Sendmessage no error" which tells me theres no exceptions to the call. Sorry for the double reply the save button is bound to 'enter' and i accidentally hit it before ending my post and the time was up when i wanted to finish my edit. I updated my post up top with the new code.

Comment: So it is sending the message base do what you are saying. Is your receiver registered to receive messages on that namespace?

Comment: Well this is embarrassing. I did not have the same namespace on both ends. Problem is solved now. I don't know what to say. Thanks a alot!!